# Оптимизация загрузки и инициализации UI

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

В общем: делаю что-то на подобие DrumPads для себя, но с некоторыми изменениями. Еще решил добавить много различных звуков из мемов xD. Две страницы по 15 кнопок, на каждую накинут звук через OnClick. Кнопки добавлял через UI unity только со своим спрайтом. Проблемка в том, что все это дело секунды 2-3 грузит, когда из главного меню заходишь в эти звуки. Можно ли как-то оптимизировать или кэшировать эти кнопки, звуки, дабы каждый раз не пришлось их грузить извне? Может есть какая-то альтернатива стандартным UI кнопкам unity, которая не так будет грузить устройство? Делаю для андроида

Comment: Большая часть времени - загрузка текстур/звуков/других ресурсов, это нормально, хотя 3 секунды - многовато для такой простой сцены.

Comment: Ну наверно с 3 секундами погорячился), но этот пролаг прямо видно, что называется вырви-глаз. Очень бесит

Comment: Я правильно понял, что из главного меню вы загружаете сцену/создаете кнопки кодом и этот процесс занимает определенное время, а дальше все идет без задержек?

Comment: Кнопки создаются не кодом, они созданы через unity UI - Button и уже готовые стоят на местах на сцене (назовем Сцена_2). По кнопке из главного меню загружается Сцена_2 со всем этим добром. И вот после нажатия на кнопку в гл. меню происходит просадка на 1 секунду +-, все загружается и показывается Сцена_2

Comment: Другими словами, вы просто загружаете другую сцену, на это нужно время, во многих приложениях (и уж тем более играх) есть подгрузка ресурсов. Чтобы не было подвисания, разработчики делают анимированный экран с индикатором прогресса. Вы можете сделать нечто подобное, сократить время загрузки не получится.

Comment: Понял вас, спасибо за ответ